# How to detect angular material swipe event ends?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angularjs-material

Thare are couple of md swipe events - `top, down, left, right`. I can pass to them some method from my controller but how to detect that this events are over, ends? I.e. i would like to show something in my view while i'm swiping my screen, when i stop doing this i would like to hid it again. How to do this? Thx for help.